# Auto-downloading files from password-protected website; wget making me crazy(er)

Tags: wget

I run a community radio station that airs radio shows from all over the world.  The audio files for these come in via RSS, Dropbox, emailed links, and by visits to private servers.  The RSS-fed shows handle themselves, as do the ones distributed via Dropbox (mostly).  The ones that take up the most time week in and week out are the ones where I have to manually go to a website, click on links, then download the associated files.

We air one show that airs every day Monday through Friday; each show comes in three parts.  I retrieve the (mp2) files by logging into the website with username and password where I'm greeted with a list of files.

Let's say the site is *h++ps://zzzzz.zz/bb/bbaudio.php*

A pop-up box allows me to put in my username and password, after which I see a list of available audio files, e.g.:

***3.19BB_part1.mp2

3.19BB_part2.mp2

3.19BB_part3.mp2***

I've tried desperately to use **wget** to automate the process to no avail.  I've tried various versions of this:

*wget –-user=USER –-password=PASS -r -nc -e robots=off -A.mp2 h++ps://zzzzz.zz/bb/bbaudio.php -P /media/yow/shows*

I've moved the username and password later in the string, I've incorporated it in the URL, I've tried it without the options and with other options, still nada!  Essentially, the server tells me to *hit the bricks*....

Truth is, I'm a pretty good radio guy, but I'm terrible at coding, syntax, and magic incantations.  Any thoughts on an easy-to-use, easy-to-understand system that will work?